# config constant to use in view, service, controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to set a constant to use in views, services and controllers.

$rootScope or .constant()?

I tried `.constant('CHAR_LIMIT', 10);` but this cannot use in view {{CHAR_LIMIT}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject it in your controller like a service and then use it (like the following):

```
var myCtrl = ['$scope','CHAR_LIMIT', function($scope,CHAR_LIMIT){
    $cope.myVar = CHAR_LIMIT;
}]
```

Comment: That means I still have to assign it to `$scope`. What if I assign it directly to `$rootScope` under `run()`?

Comment: Then you'll probably want to use it in this form:
`$parent.CHAR_LIMIT` or in a more convenient  way, inject `$rootScope` in your controller and then use `$rootScope.CHAR_LIMIT`.
Bear in mind that you can **only** use in your markup, whatever variables you assign to that specific controller's `$scope`!

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed add a constant to a module:

```
angular.module('app').constant('CHAR_LIMIT', 10);
```

and then have it injected using dependency injection anywhere Angular allows it:

```
angular.controller('someCtrl', ['CHAR_LIMIT', function(CHAR_LIMIT){

    // Use the constant here

}]);
```

If you need it to be available in all your view templates, you can add it as a property to `$rootScope` in a run block:

```
angular.run(['$rootScope', 'CHAR_LIMIT', function($rootScope, CHAR_LIMIT){
    $rootScope.CHAR_LIMIT = CHAR_LIMIT;
}]);
```

and then you can use it in your view templates like this:

```
{{CHAR_LIMIT}}
```

Notice: If you explicitly define a CHAR_LIMIT property in the child scope that is linked to the template, then that value will be used as it will 'override' the value set in the `$rootScope`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Love the app.run idea instead of declaring it in a controller!